# Change table first td after hover a first row

Tags: html, hover, css-tables

I need to change image in table, after hovering a row with this image.

Look at the code, then you will understand me.

```
table.contact tr:hover + div#email{
    background: url("http://s30.postimg.org/k9i7nej1p/email_hover.png");
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GQn2M/) is the full code

I tried `+` , `<` and `~`  to change `div after hover` but no one want to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the + so just have

```
table.contact tr:hover div#email{
    background: url("http://s30.postimg.org/k9i7nej1p/email_hover.png");
}
```

Also i recommend [CSS Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) for such a task